# Is eight handed holdem here to stay?

Tags: texas-hold-em, cash-game

So with the second shot in arm, after a little over a year, I climbed out of the cave and headed to the Bellagio to play. There I found plastic shielding on the tables and eight handed games to accommodate the plastic shields. This week I went down on Wednesday to find the plastic taken down but the games remained eight handed.

I liked the eight handed games. So I went and talked to the shift manger, a guy of known the best part of 30 years, and put my informal vote in to keep the tables eight handed. He said a lot of people like the eight handed tables and the powers that be are considering keeping the games that way going forward.

So do you like a shorter game? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I like it purely because of the extra space along with a bit faster action without feeling short handed. I saw a tweet today from the aria claiming that they are keeping things 8-handed. Bigger poker rooms will definitely be able to (and should imo) keep things 8-handed, but smaller rooms that are pay for time rather than rake may not be willing/able to reduce the table size.

Comment: I Was in playing at Bellagio Saturday, they were still 8 handed but scuttlebutt was they would be going back to 9 handed.

Answer (score 0):

8 handed poker is terrible compared to 9 handed. It’s a lot less action and disservice to the players. 8 handed means you will playing 6 or 7 handed for the majority to the night, with players going on 1 hour lunch breaks, bathroom breaks, phone call breaks, smoking breaks, quick run to put money in slots break. You will have lots and lots of chopping of the blinds. You will have lots of times pocket Aces and Kings without any callers. Your hourly rate will go down and you will find it harder to make money. This is devastating news for poker players

Comment: many players love 8 handed games. The games move much faster, and in my experience the action is a little bit better.